# Como criar uma rede local(intranet) com django?

Tags: python, django, localhost

Estou quebrando a cabeça, já testei diversos e diversos tutoriais gringos e nada funciona com excelência. Tenho um sistema feito em django em um computador comum (windows 10) e estou tentando deixar o localhost aberto para os outros computadores da rede acessar a aplicação. Já fiz diversas e diversas tentativas mas nada funciona redondo, pois com php é tão simples....

Grato, desde já.

Comment: Poderia listar essas tentativas e descrever quais foram os resultados? Isso evitará das pessoas que forem te ajudar testar soluções em vão. Ou ainda melhor, poderão apontar as possíveis soluções para fazer funcionar aquilo que você já testou e tem feito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de executar

`python manage.py runserver`

Execute o seguinte:

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`

Isso instrui ao Django que abra o servidor e aceite conexões do IP local da sua máquina. Esse seu IP, se estiver no Windows, pode ser encontrado com o comando `ipconfig`. Ele estará sob o campo "Endereço IPv4" e terá o formato `192.168.x.x` ou `10.0.x.x`. Também é possível descobri-lo acessando a página do seu roteador, provavelmente sob as configurações de DHCP.

Nesse ponto, se tentar acessar esse seu IP do seu computador ou de outro que estiver na rede local, descobrirá uma mensagem do Django com os seguintes dizeres (pro meu caso, em que meu IP local é `192.168.15.14`):

> `Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '192.168.15.14'. You may need to add '192.168.15.14' to ALLOWED_HOSTS`

Isso é uma funcionalidade de segurança do Django. Basta obedecer à mensagem e adicionar o seu IP à lista `ALLOWED_HOSTS` presente no seu `settings.py`.

No meu caso, a linha que contém a variável ficou assim:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.15.14']
```

Agora você pode acessar seu site normalmente através do seu próprio computador ou de outros dispositivos presentes na mesma rede local digitando esse IP na barra de endereços do navegador. Se conseguir acessar do seu computador mas não de outros, provavelmente é um firewall que está bloqueando o acesso. Verifique as configurações de firewall do seu computador e tente novamente.

Recomendo que configure no seu roteador um IP fixo para a máquina que hosteará o site. Assim, não terá que mexer no `ALLOWED_HOSTS` e nem verificar qual é o seu IP caso o roteador atribua um IP diferente ao seu computador depois de um tempo, como não raramente ocorre quando a configuração é DHCP.

Comment: Parceiro, valeu MESMO. Até fiz dual boot com um ubuntu para criar um server real nisso! Boa cara, mandou benzasso! Toma +1 e um joinha, é o que posso oferecer apenas kkkkk, Valeu!